# Using placement new to update a reference member?

Tags: c++, reference, object-lifetime, placement-new, reference-binding

Is the following code legal in C++?

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(T& v) : v_(v) {}

private:
    T& v_;
};

int a = 10;
Foo<int> f(a);

void Bar(int& a) {
    new (&f)Foo<int>(a);
}
```

References are not supposed to be bound twice, right?

Comment: You're not *binding* the reference `v_` twice, you *overwrite* it with the data from the object initialized by `Foo<int>(a)` in `Bar`.

Comment: "References are not supposed to be bound twice, right?" – no, but what does that have to do with the rest of your question?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, now I look back and the last sentence doesn't make sense. References cannot be bound twice, it's not like we can do anything to rebind a reference.

Comment: The code as present is legal, as long as you don't access the original object (e.g. through `f`) after that.

Comment: @appleapple why would accessing the original object through `f` be invalid? I believe this is perfectly okay as or today's standard. Both original object and the newly constructed one by `Bar()` are *transparently replaceable*, which is the (met) requirement set by the standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is perfectly invalid.

[basic.life]/1, emphasis mine:

> The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when:
>
> - if `T` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or
> - **the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.**

The placement new reuses the storage, ending the lifetime of the object denoted by `f`.

[basic.life]/7:

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage
>   which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is
>   created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a
>   pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred
>   to the original object, or the name of the original object will
>   automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the
>   new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location which the original object occupied, and
> - the new object is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), and
> - **the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static data member whose type is
>     const-qualified or a reference type**, and
> - the original object was a most derived object (1.8) of type `T` and the new object is a most derived object of type `T` (that is, they are
>     not base class subobjects).

Since the third bullet point is not satisfied, after a call to `Bar`, `f` does not refer to the object created by the placement `new`, but to the no-longer-living object previously there, and attempting to use it results in undefined behavior.

See also [CWG1776](http://wg21.link/CWG1776) and [P0137R0](http://wg21.link/P0137R0).

Comment: I don't understand something. In the placement new instruction : Does not  the creation of the new object implies the reutilization of the storage which the object occupied ? In that case after the placement new, to me, the condition : "before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released" is not met, because future use of f happen after the storage is reused. I don't understand how theses rules can be put together.

Comment: Those bullet points [no longer exist in the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8).

Answer (score -1):

It may be legal, but it's incredibly poor style. The argument to placement new is a void*, so you're telling C++ to reinterpret_cast the address of f as a void*, then using that as the location to construct something new - overwriting the original f.

Basically, don't do that.

Comment: Why not?  It’s perfectly type-safe.

Comment: Almost nothing in C++ is "perfectly type-safe" - C++ doesn't really know the meaning of this word. What if Foo was instantiated using a complex type? or even a string? The reinterpret_cast overwrites the constructed contents of the object.

Comment: Okay, in virtually all real-world cases, you want the assignment operator here, which will properly destruct a complex type.  That said, this is fine for plain old data or for an object that’s had its destructor called.  In other words, it’s C++ letting you shoot yourself in the foot again.

Comment: Even then the assignment operator is only ok if you have defined it correctly (or it's POD and you don't need one) - the default just overwrites the object.

Comment: Anything will only work if defined correctly. Yes, the default assignment operator might fail on some badly-written classes.