# placement new to reinitialize an object that has a reference member

Tags: c++

```
#include <new>

struct House { };
struct Room
{
  House& h;
  Room(House& h) : h(h) { }
};

int main()
{
   House h1;
   House h2;

   Room r(h1);

   //r = Room(h2); // This obviously won't work.

   ///
   r.~Room();
   new(&r) Room(h2); // This does work    
}
```

I have used a reference member in one place in my project and I'm wondering it's safe to use this trick as a way to reinitialize the object with a different reference.

Comment: `new(r)` should be `new(&r)`.

Comment: i've never seen `new` syntax like either of those (with parens), what does it do? i've never even seen that mentioned in any c++ book i've read

Comment: Formally, it doesn't reinitialise the object but destroys it and then creates a new one in the old one's place. Informally, this is usually a sign that your design should be reinitialised.

Comment: @johnbakers Research [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new

Comment: If you need to change what the member points to, why are you using a reference, which is designed against this? Why not a pointer? There are certainly many safer options.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as of now it is an XY problem.

Comment: @johnbakers, stop using the word **unsafe**. There is nothing unsafe about this code, it is indeed as safe as an insurance policy.

Comment: I can't get this to compile. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f192ebfa28296f7). It does compile if we use aggregate initialization [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0235a5b03fdb466).

Comment: @flatmouse, the code certainly missess constructor for `Room`, but I'd assume, this is simply an effect of code typed in the question.

Comment: @SergeyA, The part that doesn't compile in those examples isn't the missing constructor, but rather the use of `()` vs `{}`. Ah, but ok, if you had the constructor then it would work this way.

Comment: @flatmouse, compiles perfectly OK if you add a missing constructor to `Room` and `#include <new>`. See here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51cd60531a383cc5

Comment: @SergeyA, default constructor with initializer for the reference member I suppose? Without that we don't really have an MCVE. We have already found two different ways to complete it. I also only learnt about the required header from johnbakers' link. All clear to you, but not so clear for the rest of us mortals...

Comment: @flatmouse, certainly not the **default** constructor!

Comment: @SergeyA, Oops, of course. Not a default constructor. :) At least now the question is complete and clear.

Comment: @molbdnilo Placement new does not necessarily mean a bad design. Many libraries (including the standard library) use placement new to create and manage memory pools, implement garbage collection, or for performance and exception safety. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/222578/4975646) has a good explanation of the uses for placement new.

Comment: @callyalater That's what I wrote; "X is usually a sign of Y" is a very different thing from "X necessarily means Y".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using placement new is a valid practice. It is safe, and your usage is semantically correct. However, I can't answer the question of applicability in your particular case without your particular case. Provided code doesn't show your case, so I am willing to consider it an XY problem until I hear more.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was safe to do it because I was not sure. I didn't want to start writing code that may be unsafe.

Comment: @Phantom, define *safe*.

Comment: @Phantom, perhaps phrase the question in terms of undefined behavior and memory leaks?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33515129/6053907  i'm guessing the following only applies if I skip the ~destructor() call? `the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static data member whose type is const-qualified or a **reference type**, and`

Comment: @Phantom, as long as you call the destructor, you are ok.