# Using placement `new`'s result on a object with a reference member

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, c++17, placement-new

The ["Using placement new to update a reference member?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514809/using-placement-new-to-update-a-reference-member) question shows this example (simplified):

```
struct Foo { int& v_; };

int a, b;
Foo f{a};

new (&f) Foo{b};

assert(&f.v_ == &a); // UB
```

Accessing `f` through its original name is definitely UB as [explained by T.C. in the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33515129/598696). I know that `std::launder` can be used to work around this:

```
assert(&std::launder(&f)->v_ == &a); // OK, will fire the assert
```

But what about using the pointer returned by placement `new`? I.e.

```
auto p = new (&f) Foo{b};    
assert(&(p->v_) == &a); // UB? OK?
```

In this case, we're not referring to the object through its original name, but through whatever placement `new` returned.

**Is this undefined behavior or allowed by the Standard?**

Comment: Your code is undefined behavior because the destructor is called through the original name.  For a local with automatic storage duration, there's no preventing this.

Comment: @BenVoigt: would the behavior be defined if I were to manually control the lifetime of the object? (e.g. using a `std::aligned_storage_t`)

Comment: `f.~Foo(); auto p = new (&f) Foo{b};` should be fine.

Comment: @BenVoigt Is this true? We know local objects will get destroyed automatically, but does standard explicitly say that their dtors will be called "through the original name"?

Comment: @C.M.: No, there's a parallel rule with exactly the same restrictions as exist for use of the original name.  So it is UB, no question.

Comment: @Jarod42: Not fine, the automatic destructor call will still occur on the wrong object.  An explicit destructor call doesn't inhibit the automatic call.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: That would help; it's only a problem when there is an automatic destructor call.

Comment: @BenVoigt can you refer me to related place in standard? (or at least give me a pointer (lol) where to look for it)

Comment: @C.M.: Turns out you have to fill in some of the gaps.  `[stmt.jump]` and `[stmt.dcl]` make it clear that the "variable" or "object with automatic storage duration" is automatically destroyed.  `[basic.life]` tells us that things will be ok if a new object of the same type is substituted for the original, at the time when execution leaves the scope.  And the rule for use of old names/pointers/references tells us that objects containing const or reference members cannot be substituted.  Together, this equates to UB.

Comment: @C.M.: Working out the meaning of the various rules gets much easier if you consider they are structured to permit constant propagation on `const` data members, and inlining usages of reference data members.

Comment: @BenVoigt So, it is ok to replace local object with another one (of the same type) as long as it doesn't contain const or reference members? I could see why you wouldn't want to allow replacing references, but const? constness is essentially a gimmick... Can you elaborate a bit how you came up to a conclusion about const members? (with references to standard, if possible :))

Comment: @C.M.: Follow the second link in the question...  And the reasoning is that `struct { int a; const int b; } x = { 1, 42 }; f(x); cout << x.b;` the compiler can avoid reading `x.b` and just do `cout << 42;`  If instead of `cout` that variable was controlling a loop, allowing the compiler to unroll... it's a rather big deal to treat `const` objects with constant initializers as actually constant.  And between this rule and the `const_cast` restrictions, the compiler actually can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
auto p = new (&f) Foo{b};    
assert(&(p->v_) == &a); // UB? OK?
```

Is well-defined. The assert will trigger. `new` creates a new object, and `p` points to that new object. That is all perfectly fine. We're reusing `f`'s storage, and there are a lot of rules in [[basic.life]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life) about what is OK and not OK about how you can use *old* names - there are rules about how you can use `f`, previous pointers to `f`, etc. You cannot reuse `&f` without `launder`-ing it. There rules about how and when you can call destructors in this case, or what about reusing storage for static storage or const objects - none of which matter here either.

But `p` is a new thing - it just refers to the new object. And `p->v_` is the new `int&` that you created that refers to `b`. That is not the same object as `a`, so the pointers compare unequal.

Comment: The destructor rule is going to matter greatly at the end of the scope.

Comment: @Ben Our type is trivially destructible, so it doesn't affect us.