# Does std::optional<>::emplace() invalidate references to the inner value?

Tags: c++, option-type, lifetime, stdoptional

Consider the following fragment (assume that `T` is trivially constructible and trivially destructible):

```cpp
std::optional<T> opt;
opt.emplace();
T& ref = opt.value();
opt.emplace();
// is ref guaranteed to be valid here?
```

From [the definition of `std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) we know that the contained instance is guaranteed to be allocated inside the `std::optional` container, hence we know that the reference `ref` will always be referring to the same memory location. Are there circumstances where said reference will not retain validity after the pointed-to object is destroyed and then constructed again?

Comment: IIRC if the object has const or reference members then it is UB to access the new object using a reference to the old object.

Comment: References cease to be valid when the object lifetime ends. Emplacing causes the lifetime of the old object to end, and a new object is created in the same memory. So the old reference is invalid. If you had assigned a new value, then the old object is reassigned, not destroyed

Comment: its more an issue of placement new rather than `optional::emplace` specifically and this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514809/using-placement-new-to-update-a-reference-member

Comment: Okay thanks guys. @RaymondChen if you posted your comment as a response I would accept it as this is what I was looking for.

Comment: the top answer actually has all needed to answer this question. I am just reluctant to close as dupe, because the question is coming from a different direction

Comment: @NathanOliver This changed in C++20 (https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1971r0.html#RU007). And it isn't relevant here since there are no const-qualified or reference members

Comment: @RaymondChen Is the pointer also invalidated `T* ptr = &opt.value();`? Could we use `*std::launder(&ref)`?

Comment: @Artyer Oh, neat, thanks.  Good to know.

Comment: @Artyer I'm wondering if you're planning on writing an answer? I think this question deserves a full answer, even if the OP has decided that they no longer need one, since other people might come across it and not understand the comments. If you don't want to write it, I can.

Comment: @Artyer points out that I missed a clause in **[basic.life]** which says that references carry over if the objects are "transparently replaceable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++20 has the following rule, [basic.life]/8:

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if the original object is transparently replaceable (see below) by the new object. An object *o*<sub>1</sub> is transparently replaceable by an object *o*<sub>2</sub> if:
>
> - the storage that *o*<sub>2</sub> occupies exactly overlays the storage that *o*<sub>1</sub> occupied, and
> - *o*<sub>1</sub> and *o*<sub>2</sub> are of the same type (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), and
> - *o*<sub>1</sub> is not a complete const object, and
> - neither *o*<sub>1</sub> nor *o*<sub>2</sub> is a potentially-overlapping subobject (6.7.2), and
> - either *o*<sub>1</sub> and *o*<sub>2</sub> are both complete objects, or *o*<sub>1</sub> and *o*<sub>2</sub> are direct subobjects of objects *p*<sub>1</sub> and *p*<sub>2</sub> ,
>   respectively, and *p*<sub>1</sub> is transparently replaceable by *p*<sub>2</sub>.

This suggests that as long as `T` is not const-qualified, destroying the `T` inside an `std::optional<T>` and then recreating it should result in a reference to the old object automatically referring to the new object. As pointed out in the comments section, this is a change from the old behaviour, abolishing a requirement that `T` must not contain a non-static data member of const-qualified or reference type. (Edit: I previously asserted that the change was made retroactively, as I confused it with a different change in C++20. I am not sure whether the resolution to RU 007 and US 042 as indicated in [N4858](https://wg21.link/N4858) were made retroactive, but I suspect the answer is yes, because the change was needed to fix code involving standard library templates that was probably not *intended* to be broken from C++11 through C++17.)

However, we are making the assumption that the new `T` object is being created "before the storage which the [old] object occupied is reused or released". If I were writing an "adversarial" implementation of the standard library, I could set it up so that the `emplace` call reuses the underlying storage prior to creating the new `T` object. This would prevent the old `T` object from being transparently replaced by the new one.

How might an implementation "reuse" the storage? Typically, the underlying storage might be declared like this:

```
union {
    char no_object;
    T object;
};
```

When the default constructor of `optional` is called, `no_object` is initialized (the value does not matter)<sup>1</sup>. An `emplace()` call checks whether there is a `T` object or not (by checking a flag that is not shown here). If a `T` object is present, then `object.~T()` is called. Finally, something similar to `construct_at(addressof(object))` is called in order to construct the new `T` object.

Not that any implementation would ever do this, but you could imagine an implementation that, *in between* the calls to `object.~T()` and `construct_at(addressof(object))`, re-initializes the `no_object` member. This would be a "reuse" of the storage that was previously occupied by `object`. This would imply that the requirements of [basic.life]/8 are not met.

Of course, the practical answer to your question is that (1) there is no reason for an implementation to do something like this, and (2) even if an implementation did it, the developers would ensure that your code still behaves as if the `T` object was transparently replaced. Your code is reasonable under the assumption that the standard library implementation is reasonable, and compiler developers do not like to break code with that property, since doing so would needlessly aggravate their users.

But if a compiler developer were inclined to break your code (based on the argument that the more undefined behaviour there is, the more the compiler can optimize) then they could break your code even *without* changing the `<optional>` header file. The user is required to treat the standard library like a "black box" that only guarantees what the standard explicitly guarantees. So under a pedantic reading of the standard, it's *unspecified* whether or not attempting to access `ref` after the second `emplace` call has undefined behaviour. If it's unspecified whether it's UB, then the compiler is allowed to start treating it as UB whenever it wants.

<sup>1</sup> The reason for this is historical; C++17 requires that a `constexpr` constructor initialize exactly one variant member of a union. This rule was abolished in C++20, so a C++20 implementation could omit the `no_object` member.